# Path Testing If Isnumeric

Tags: vb.net, testing, exit

This may be a stupid question, and if so, I apologize.

I'm trying to figure out the exact number of paths for a bit of code I'm working on in VB. I understand path testing. Mostly. But I come up short on IF statements with an ELSE condition that exits the sub.

My program just has 4 IF statements that check 4 text inputs with isnumeric. If they are numeric, everything continues, calculations are done, and results display in the labels. Everything is right with the world. If, however, an input isn't numeric, the ELSE part of the IF statements pop a text box about the problem and exit the sub to avoid errors. Are these ELSE statements individual paths, with the expected result of exiting the sub? Or is it only a path if the program continues on, whether to another IF statement or to the end display of the results?

I appreciate any clarification that can be provided.

Comment: Instead of explaining what your code does, kindly _do_ include your code in the question.

Comment: I apologize, Ahmed. I would include said code, but I am away from my main computer and don't have access to it at the moment.

Comment: If you exit the sub, that's it. The [Exit Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/exit-statement) documentation explains it clearly ;)

Comment: This I understand, but is this a path to be tested? Therein lies my confusion.

Comment: @BrisingrChetowa If the code exits the sub, nothing else, including the conditions, in the If...Then...Else statement will be executed, if that is what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the project in Solution Explorer, and select Analyze, and then Calculate Code Metrics. The cyclomatic complex (which counts the number of decisions the code makes) will be displayed.

For the following, the cyclomatic complexity is 5. (Yes, the Else statements are individual paths.)

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim text1 As String = "abc"
        Dim text2 As String = "1bc"
        Dim text3 As String = "12c"
        Dim text4 As String = "123"

        If Not IsNumeric(text1) Then
            Console.WriteLine("Error -- text1!")
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf Not IsNumeric(text2) Then
            Console.WriteLine("Error -- text2!")
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf Not IsNumeric(text3) Then
            Console.WriteLine("Error -- text3!")
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf Not IsNumeric(text4) Then
            Console.WriteLine("Error -- text4!")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Console.WriteLine("Do happy path processing")
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: We have been in the .Net era for quite a while. It is time to lose the old VB6 `.IsNumeric` and replace it with `.TryParse`. Use the .`TryParse` method of the actual numeric type that you want to convert to. It will tell you whether the conversion was successful and also give the converted value.

Comment: The question concerned cyclomatic complexity, not parsing numeric values.

Comment: It is kept around for backward compatibility. New code should use the .net methods. They have been optimized. It is much easier to move back and forth to C# if you use .net methods.

Comment: Once you have used .IsNumberic you still have to convert your string to a numeric data type. TryParse does that for you.